# Yellow Pages Search

Tags: performance, programming-challenge, search, memory-optimization, pascal

I've written code in Free Pascal based on a contest problem (The contest insists that I have to write with Pascal).  It works like charm, but I think it still need some improvements, from memory usage to runtime.

> **Input Format**
>
> First line is  `n` (Number of people in the Yellow Pages) and `q`
>   (Number of people to search) `{1 <= n <= 10000}` and `{1 <= q <=
>   10000}`
>
> Next `n` lines are Yellow Pages entries, each line is the name and the
>   phone number, space delimited. The name is uppercase letters with
>   maximum length of 15, while the length of the phone number is exactly
>   7 digits.
>
> Next `q` lines are the people to search, also in uppercase letters
>   with maximum length 15.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Output is `q` lines, where each line is the phone number of the people
>   to search
>
> **Input Sample**
>
> ```
> 10 5
> AARON 8468431
> BEN 1573457
> GREGORY 1765743
> JACK 3746843
> JILL 1357891
> MICHAEL 1375638
> MONET 1357562
> SHEILA 1378651
> TERRY 8756345
> YIN 1781945
> GREGORY
> YIN
> AARON
> MONET
> JACK
> ```
>
> **Output Sample**
>
> ```
> 1765743
> 1781945
> 8468431
> 1357562
> 3746843
> ```

**My Code**

```
program YellowPages;

type string7 = String[7];

var
  namearray : Array of shortstring;
  numberarray, searcharray : Array of string7;
  input, name, search : shortstring;
  number : string7;
  n, q, iter1, iter2 : word;

procedure SplitInput(input : shortstring; var name : shortstring; var number : string7);
var 
  iter_proc, hitspace : byte;
begin
  hitspace := pos(' ', input);
  name := '';
  number := '';
  for iter_proc := 1 to length(input) do
  begin
    if iter_proc < hitspace then name := name + input[iter_proc];
    if iter_proc > hitspace then number := number + input[iter_proc];
  end;
end;

begin
  readln(n, q);
  setlength(namearray, n);
  setlength(numberarray, n);
  setlength(searcharray, q);
  for iter1 := 0 to (n - 1) do
  begin
    readln(input);
    SplitInput(input, name, number);
    namearray[iter1] := name;
    numberarray[iter1] := numberarray;
  end;
  for iter1 := 0 to (q - 1) do
  begin
    readln(search);
    for iter2 := 0 to (n - 1) do
    begin
      if namearray[iter2] = search then break;
    end;
    searcharray[iter1] := numberarray[iter2];
  end;
  for iter1 := 0 to (q - 1) do
  begin
    writeln(searcharray[iter1]);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 6 → 3. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is switch from using parallel arrays to using a single array of [records](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu19.html#x43-500003.3.2). Create a record that holds both the name and the phone number of each person in the phonebook, like this:

```
Type
    Contact = Record 
        name : shortstring;
        number : String7;
        end;
```

Once you've done that, you should sort the array based on each contact's name. The [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm is fairly easy to implement and is usually quite fast in most cases.

Once you have the array sorted, instead of searching through the entire phonebook from the beginning, you can use a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find each record you want and get the phone number from it. A binary search should never require more than log2(n) comparisons (where n is the size of the array you're searching). Whereas your search requires on average n/2 comparisons. So for 100 entries, you'd never perform more than ~8 comparisons with a binary search, whereas you'd usually do around 50 using a linear search.

I haven't used FreePascal or any other Pascal compiler in a long time. It's possible that they have some built-in sorting and searching procedures that you could use. But it's not hard to implement the ones mentioned above.

Also, in `SplitInput()` you're manually copying the data from one string to another. Usually there's a library with a procedure for copying a string or a part of a string. These will usually be faster than writing your own. (For example, in C you could use `memcpy()` or `strncpy()`. I'm not sure if there's an equivalent in Pascal.)

Comment: I think I don't need quicksort, because the yellowpage entry input is already alphabetically ordered.

Comment: Nice suggestion for the records. I've got `SplitInput()` updated to use `Copy()`. The only thing that bugs me is the binary search for the yellowpage record. Because the type to search is a string and the one doing comparing is an integer, I can't relate both. I'm considering doing an `ord()` check for the first character, but there will be names with same first character. What should I do?

Comment: @RyoArmanda good point about not needing the sort. Phone books are already sorted! It turns out that Pascal directly supports string comparisons. So if you have `a < b` where a and b are strings, you'll get the correct answer.

Comment: I didn't know about that, thanks! Binary search is a success. Any more tips? If no more tips, I'll wrap this code up nice.

Comment: That's all I can think of at the moment. Good luck!